# get parameter in servlet for for each loop

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page  like this

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}" >
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="description.html">
                                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.base64EncodedImage}" alt="image">
                                                        <div class="caption" align="center">
                                                            <p>
                                                            <h4>${product.name}</h4>
                                                            <h5>cost:Rs ${product.price}/-</h5>
```

i fetch the productimage,price,name using for each.from for each in jsp i have to get parameter values in servlet using  `request.getParameter()` and have to implement in another page using those parameters

I have a tumbnails in page.when we click on it it redirects into another page.there we have to set particular tumnails image,product name,price

help me how to get that parameters in servlet class 
please check image in this link--->>
[I have to get the Product name,product price, image from 1 tumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bw2w.jpg)
Thanks !

Comment: Which values you want in Servlet?

Comment: It is totally unclear, what your problem is. Please explain it in more detail. What servlet? When it is called? What is the relation to your JSP page? You should also take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Question not clear. You want details of particular product or all products.. Are you taking input from user?

Comment: sorry i am fetched image,productname,productprice in one page in tumbnails by using for each.now i have to select particular project it have to get product image,name, price in another page using servlet

Comment: Please help me I edited the question and attach image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide hyperlink on image and send all the details you want on servlet as query string

```
 <a href="ServletName?name=${product.name}&price=${product.price}">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.base64EncodedImage}"  alt="image"/>
</a>
```

**OR**

Send only product id and in servlet fetch all product details for that id from database

```
 <a href="ServletName?id=${product.id}">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.base64EncodedImage}"  alt="image"/>
 </a>
```

Comment: @vamsi krishna Use second option